# If I have an SBT multi-project build, how can I make A's test dependencies not leak in to B's tests

Tags: scala, testing, dependencies, sbt

So, I have an SBT project with modules A and B.

- A depends on B.
- A and B's normal project packages are compatible.
- A has a package for testing that is incompatible with a package that B
  uses for tests.
- A does not depend on B's test packages
- A's tests fail, because of the test package incompatibility

In my eyes, this failure is invalid, because A's tests do not depend on B's tests.

I'm using

```
A.dependsOn(B % "compile->compile;test->compile")
```

meaning

- A's compile depends on B's compile
- A's test depends on B's compile.

Am I doing something wrong?

[Here's the actual build file](https://github.com/Jacoby6000/scoobie/blob/feature/split-submodules-better/build.sbt). Relevant project is `doobieSupport23` depending on `core`

[Here's the build error](https://travis-ci.org/Jacoby6000/scoobie/jobs/133411201#L385).  You can see that it's pulling in scalaz 7.2 in the build, but it should only be pulling scalaz 7.1.6

Comment: I don't get from your question title, do B's tests fail or do A's tests fail?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added more detail.  A's tests fail.

Comment: Going over the dependency graph step by step, I was able to figure out that I had some un-necessary dependencies in packages that were causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had specified in the issue works exactly as expected.

The problem ended up being that my build file had an extraneous dependency that I had just glossed over.  That dependency was causing doobie 3.0 being pulled in where I only expected doobie 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely not in projects depending on each other, the configuration `"compile->compile;test->compile"`, as it seems to me, is perfectly valid for what you need to achieve.

What's causing the problem is that your `libraryDependencies` are shared due to A being dependent on B. Fortunately, sbt allows to manage dependencies quite precisely.

The easiest suggestion would be to apply a newer version of the conflicting dependency to a scope as narrow as possible - meaning, if scalaz 7.2.0 is only needed in core's tests, so be it!

```
lazy val core = project(...)
  .settings(libraryDependencies in Test += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz" % "7.2.0")
lazy val doobieSupport23 = project(...).dependsOn(core)
  .settings(libraryDependencies in Test += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz" % "7.1.6")
```

If you can't make it work because the newer version is actually used in other core's dependencies, the following trick may do it:

```
val scalazOld = "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz" % "7.1.6"
val scalazNew = "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz" % "7.2.0"

lazy val core = project(...)
  .settings(libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz" % "7.2.0")

lazy val doobieSupport23 = project(...).dependsOn(core)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies in Test += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz" % "7.1.6" force()
  )
```

Note the `force()` combinator. I'm not sure this way it won't fail in runtime due to incompatible classes in classpath.

Comment: hm, weird.  I thought that `... % "test"` was supposed to achieve this.  I'll try it out and see what happens.  thanks for the tip!

Comment: This still doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Problem seems to actually be `doobie 2.3` getting evicted by `doobie 3.0`